# How to change disabled color in MRTK Interactable buttons correctly?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I am working to an application with unity3D and MRTK package for hololens2 and I am trying to change the color of a toggle when it is disabled.

The toggle has an Interactable script on it with many profiles, one of them has two themes for the selected state that are "InteractableActivateTheme" and "Interactable color children theme".
I used successfully the latter to change color of the toggle when selected using the theme field "Pressed" and "Default", but I am not able to use the "Disabled" field in any case.

[Screenshot of the profile I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdCus.png)

I disable the toggle by code setting the state to disabled in this way:

```
PlaceToggle.SetState(InteractableStates.InteractableStateEnum.Disabled, true);
PlaceToggle.enabled = true;
```

The toggle disables itself but the color remains red has set in the "Default" State Properties of the "InteractableColorChildrenTheme".
I also tried to change the color by code like this, but I had no result:

```
 var activeThemes = PlaceToggle.ActiveThemes;
            foreach (InteractableThemeBase itb in activeThemes)
            {
                if (itb is InteractableColorChildrenTheme)
                {
                    Debug.Log(" changing state property");

                    var property = itb.StateProperties;
                    oldColor = itb.StateProperties[0].Values[0].Color;
                    itb.StateProperties[0].Values[0].Color = Color.gray;
                }
            }
```

Any idea on how could I understand what it is  happening and why it is not working??
Thanks you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code to disable your button:

```
    buttonInteractable = this.GetComponent<Interactable>();
    buttonInteractable.IsEnabled = false;
```

Verified in MRTK2.7 & Unity 2019.4.22.